# ASP.NET Core MVC NoFun solution

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I cloned ASP.NET Core MVC repository and in source code I found two solutions i.e.
Mvc.sln and Mvc.NoFun.sln. Can someone please throw some light on Mvc.NoFun.sln?
What is this NoFun solution and why it exists along with main solution i.e. Mvc.sln?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MVC.NoFun.sln is a solution that has everything that Mvc.sln has EXCEPT functional tests.

You can see the comments from when the MVC.NoFun.sln was created here: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/commit/be4a6c8d98fa6122be2e26b2e8830dc6b36ed9fd